# Qt slot and class inheritation

Tags: qt, qt4, signals-slots, qt4.7

In the parent class , i have a slot setup in constructor:

```
  Class DummyParent 
{
     protected:
        QWebPage page;

     public slots:
          DummyParent() 
          {
              connect (&page , SIGNAL(...) , SLOT(replyFinir(bool));
          } 

          void replyFinir (bool ok)
          {
               // handle reply messages
          }
  };
```

Now i have another class derived from DummyParent:

```
class DummyChild
{ 
    public slots:
        void replyFinir (bool ok)
        {

        }
}
```

Now i have the problem , since the slot connection setup in DummyParent's constructor , so it's connecting to the old handler , not the current one.

How can i let DummyChild::page call it's own replyFinir(bool) function ?

Comment: Got Q_OBJECT macros everywhere? (esp. in derived class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you forgotten `virtual` in the base class replyfinir?

Alternately just disconnect/reconnect the signal in the derived class ctor